# Removing string before alphabets

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want to remove the characters or string before the occurrence of alphabets.

For example consider

> "--Test-T1" , "---Test-T2" , "----Test-T3" .

In the above strings i want to remove the hyphens before alphabets start and want to keep hyphens after that. I tried substring, remove `LastIndexOf()+1`, `Regex.Replace` but none did work. Please guide me how to achieve it.

Comment: `"--Test-T1".TrimStart('-')`? What should be the behavior in case of `--1Test-Test--`? "but none did work" - why? What regex did you try?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked..! thank you very much sir. And if i want to remove hyphens in middle not at beginning, is it possible to achieve?

Comment: What is the test sample/expected result? In the middle - does it mean not at the end? `--1-2--3-` -> ??

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew replaced with space

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes sir, not in the end

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, but probably `Regex.Replace(s, @"^-+|-+$|(-+)", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? " " : m.Value);`. Replace `(-+)` with `(-)` to replace each single hyphen with a space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to just remove the `-` symbols from the start of a string, a mere

```
var res = s.TrimStart('-');
```

will do. If you need to make sure there are alphabets after the leading hyphens, use a regex:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"^-+(?=[a-zA-Z])", "");
```

Here,

- `^` - asserts the position at the string start
- `-+` - matches and consumes 1+ hyphens
- `(?=[a-zA-Z])` - the positive lookahead checks if there is an ASCII letter after the hyphens (but does not consume the letter, it is not part of the match value).

Alternatively, use a capturing group based version:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, @"^-+([a-zA-Z])", "$1");
```

Here, the letter is consumed, but since we've captured it, `$1` restores it in the result.

Note that `[a-zA-Z]` can be replaced with `\p{L}` to match any Unicode letter.